# How do you store custom user data in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, user-controls

I may be overlooking a question like this, but I couldn't find it.  I have an asp.net site with C# codebehind, and I have a working means of creating user accounts, passwords, and associating other data with each user.  I started this site by creating a web application, and the login/register functions were all included and work fine.  I also have a database that the user can search and display data on the site (all of this also works).  However, I want the user to be able to search the database for data, and then be able to go back to pages that they've saved as pages that they're "following."  All I would need to store would be a unique identifier from the database to note that the person wanted to follow that page.  Where would be the best place to store these values?  Could I do so by saving the data in the aspnetdb database?  If so, how would I write custom values in this database if using an asp.net web application?

Comment: Store the information in a database.. And when they want to display 'remembered pages' you display the dataset..

Comment: Each of your users should have a unique ID already, build a new table to hold the "following" data and then just reference the unique ID of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET's [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) feature, you'll probably want to use the  [MembershipUser.ProviderKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.provideruserkey%28v=vs.100%29) as the unique ID mentioned by @dcreight.  Use it to access your own table.  I would not recommend writing into the aspnetdb directly.